# Python script to delete all csv file from folder except file starting with specific name

Tags: python

Using python i want to delete all csv files from download folder except file starting with name fakeowner-mis.

Complete file name look like:- fakeowner-mis_2021-11-16_to_2021-11-18.csv

I am new to python please help!

Below is the code which i have tried but not working.

```html
path = "C:/Users/Downloads/*fakeowner-mis*"
   for filename not in glob.glob(path):
    os.remove(filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like:

```
path = "C:/Users/Downloads/*.csv"
for f in glob.glob(path):
    if f.rsplit('/')[-1].startswith('fakeowner-mis'):
        continue
    print(f)
    #os.remove(f)
```

*NB. I commented the line to actually delete the files, check first that it works as you expect, then uncomment it*

Comment: Hi mozway, this code delete all files. I do not want to delete files starting with name fakeowner-mis.

Comment: This should continue if the file starts with fakeowner-mis, skipping it in the remove process.

Comment: @Rajesh please try it, the code should delete all CSV files except those starting with "fakeowner-mis". The `continue` is here to skip those files. Actually the code above only prints the files to be deleted. It deletes only if you uncomment the last line (if you remove the `#`)

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import glob
```

## List all of the files in the folder test

```
print(glob.glob("../test/*"))
```

## List only file with CSV as an extension

```
print(glob.glob("../test/*.csv"))
```

## List all files with firstname as **fakeowner-mis**

```
print(glob.glob("../test/fakeowner-mis*.csv"))
```

## Remove file from the folder

```
for file in glob.glob("../test/fakeowner-mis*.csv"):
    os.remove(file)
```

*fakeowner-mis* : This means where ever the substring contains *fakeowner-mis* to delete those file.
Which need to be changed as ***fakeowner-mis*.csv*** in order to work for start of string.